# replacing multiple utf-8 characters in php

Tags: php, utf-8, warnings, preg-replace

I have a string with multiple utf-8 characters that look like this

```
\u00b4, \u2019, \u201b, \u2032
```

I want to replace these with the following html character

```
&#39;
```

I'm using the following php code to replace these

```
$search  = "(\\u00b4|\\u2019|\\u201b|\\u2032)"; 
$replace = "&#39;";

$result = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

I keep getting the following warning, and $result is null

```
Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \\L, \\l, \\N, \\U, or \\u at offset 2 in /...
```

I have no idea what to do. Any ideas on how to proceed with replacing these utf8 characters is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When doing a preg match on specific character codes, you need to use the \x hexadecimal notation, not unicode notation -- those look like unicode values.

```
$search  = "(\xb4|\x2019|\x201b|\x2032)";
```

Comment: the string that I have has been json_encoded, for some reason the utf8 code is an actual string \u2019... I really have to match that exact string...

Answer (score 0):

```
$unicode = "\u00b4 \u2019 \u201b \u2032";
$unicode = preg_replace('/\\\\u[^ ]+/im', "&#39;\r\n", $unicode);
echo $unicode;
```

You didn't escape the backslashes correctly, you need 2 extra backslashes:

```
\\\\
```